# Change a customfield from an <input> to a <textarea> in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a few customfields that are visable from the front and, of course, display as input textboxes however I need them to be textareas instead. Is it possible to change how customfields output? If so what would I need to do to make this change?

Answer (score 0):

please read more about

get_post_meta (to display your meta_data linked to the post)
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

update_post_meta (to update your meta data linked to the post)
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta

isset (to have your submission button to update_post_meta(needs to be on top of the page))
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php